# Discord.py — discord.ext.commands.errors.MemberNotFound If I try to ban a user who is not on the server

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am trying to write a command that can ban a user Using ID and @. But there is a problem: the bot cannot ban a user if he is not on the server.

There's code:

```
async def ban(ctx, member: discord.Member = None, *, reason=None):
    await member.ban()
    await ctx.send("You have banned a user")
```

There's result:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\FreezeGames\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 939, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\FreezeGames\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 855, in invoke
    await self.prepare(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\FreezeGames\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 789, in prepare
    await self._parse_arguments(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\FreezeGames\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 697, in _parse_arguments
    transformed = await self.transform(ctx, param)
  File "C:\Users\FreezeGames\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 552, in transform
    return await self.do_conversion(ctx, converter, argument, param)
  File "C:\Users\FreezeGames\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 505, in do_conversion
    return await self._actual_conversion(ctx, converter, argument, param)
  File "C:\Users\FreezeGames\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 451, in _actual_conversion
    ret = await instance.convert(ctx, argument)
  File "C:\Users\FreezeGames\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\converter.py", line 195, in convert
    raise MemberNotFound(argument)
discord.ext.commands.errors.MemberNotFound: Member "467762820734386196" not found.
```

UPDATED: Using "member: discord.User", how do I write a condition if the user has a specific role?

Thanks in advance for any help you can offer, and let me know if you need any more information out of me.

Answer (score 1):

A member converter is going to be useless if you want to get a user who is not on your server. Use the user converter instead:

```
async def ban(ctx, member: discord.User, *, reason=None):
    await member.ban()
    await ctx.send("You have banned a user")
```

Comment: I've used "discord.Member" before, but then I get a problem: How can I check if a user has certain roles? Example if using discord.Member: "if get (member.roles, id = 867132420489871411)"

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure what you mean by that. Is that role check in the same ban command? If yes you can just get the member with `Guild.get_member` (https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/master/api.html?highlight=get%20member#discord.Guild.get_member). If it's in another command you can of course just use the member converter, just use whichever one suits your command.

Answer (score -1):

```
async def ban(ctx, member: discord.Member = None, *, reason=None):
    running = True
    while running:
            try:
                    await member.ban()
                    await ctx.send("You have banned a user")
            except:
                    continue
            else:
                    running = False
```

This could possibly work. I am not sure though.